# Access string stored in secret manager from CDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am storing the Codestar connection string for Bitbucket in Secret manager. How can I retrieve it in the CDK app:

I am trying with:

```
// Get Bitbucket Connection String
const bitbucketConnectionString = Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(this, "bitbucketConnectionString", "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:1000000000:secret:BitbucketCloudConnection-abcdef0");


// SourceAction
const sourceAction = new BitBucketSourceAction({
    actionName: 'BitbucketSource',
    owner: 'abc',
    repo: repoName,
    output: sourceOutputArtifact,
    connectionArn: bitbucketConnectionString,
})
```

`bitbucketConnectionString` is not a string though.

1. How do I access the secret value which is actually a connectionString stored in Secret Manager.
2. What is the right way to replace region and accountId with Pseudo variables in the connection string;

   arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:1000000000:secret:BitbucketCloudConnection-abcdef0

Answer (score 1):

1. The account and region reference can be set up on the basis of the environment variables you have. You should be able to use a `this.account` or `this.region` to reference the current stack/constructs environment details.